# Python file write permissions differ from user windows 7

Tags: python, shell, permissions, copy

I am trying to copy a file across our local network to a shared folder using a python script but I keep running into a permissions issue. I've tried shutil, os.system and subprocess.POpen with similar results.  Both my box and the server are running Windows 7.

In cmd prompt, I can successfully

```
copy a.file \\server\destination.file
```

However, from the same command prompt I run

```
python moveFile.py
```

which has the following code

```
import os,subprocess,string

file = "a.file"
destination = "\\\\server\\destination.file"
command = "copy " + file " " + destination
if os.path.exists(destination):
   print("Destination access:" + str(os.access(destination,os.W_OK)))
   subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)
```

The output is

```
"Destination access: False"
" Access is denied.
    0 file(s) copied."
```

This leads me to believe that the python script has different permissions than my user. Anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions of the python executable? It is located in `c:\python27\` or something. On my box, regular users only have read and execute permissions, which *should* be enough. But I'm running as an admin, so I get full control. Try adjusting that.